# Not marked as Serializable error

Tags: c#, serialization, binary-serialization

I have a class 'Entity'

```
[Serializable]
public class Entity
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Entity> ChildEntity { get; set; } 
}
```

I would notice that it has property ChildEntity which is a list of same class Entity.

Question1. Do I have to explicitly serialize this list ? Or Serializable attribute on the class will do that work for me.

Now when I try to Serialize this class using Binary Serializer I get exception saying this class is not marked as Serializable.

I think the exception occurs when it tries to serialize childEntities.

Here is my code for serializing.

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        try
        {
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
           //TODO
    }
    }
}
```

I also have a class from where the List of Entity Class is getting populated.

```
[Serializable]
public class AllEntity
{
    public Guid ParentId {get; set; }
    public Guid Id {get; set;} //childId
    public string Desc {get; set;}
}
```

I am performing recursion to build the List of Entity class based on Parent Child Relationship.

```
public IEnumerable<Entity> Build(IEnumerable<AllEntity> allentity)
{
    //recursivey builds List if Entity class
}
```

**Exception Message:**

> Type
>   'System.LINQ.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[[Common.Models.AllEntity,
>   Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Token=null],
>   [Common.Models.Entity, Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   Token=null]' in Assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, Token=null' is not marked as Serializable

Comment: What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message, source, exception type and inner exception?  The full exception message should explain more.

Comment: Does it makes any sense?

Comment: Can you please post your complete code to look into.

Comment: Your problem is that `IEnumerable<Entity> ChildEntity` does not actually refer to a `List<ChildEntity>`, it refers to an the unevaluated result of a `.Where()` linq query.  Materialize it with `ToList()` before serialization.

Comment: @dbc You are a life saver !! :D

Comment: @siddharth - shall I make it an answer?

Comment: @dbc Yes, that solved my problem

Comment: @siddharth - OK, will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated by the exception, your problem is that, in at least one `Entity` instance, the property `IEnumerable<Entity> ChildEntity` does not actually refer to a `List<ChildEntity>`, it refers to the unevaluated result of a [`.Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx). LINQ query.

Materialize it with [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) before storage.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with below code its working fine.

```
Entity ea = new Entity();
ea.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
var li = new List<Entity>();
li.Add(new Entity { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });
ea.ChildEntity = li;
DeepClone<Entity>(ea);
```

Just you need to mark class as [Serializable].